# How can I synchronize physical files manually in a Kentico web farm?

Tags: asp.net, synchronization, kentico

We have a non-standard Kentico architecture which Kentico have advised is supported as long as synchronization of physical files between load balanced servers is disabled and handled manually. What is the correct way to manually synchronize web farm server files? I wondered about using a tool like [DirSync](http://www.dirsyncpro.org/) but assume this would require one server to act as the primary, whereas with Kentico a new media file, for example, may be initially saved to any of the physical servers.

I'm hoping to identify a definitive solution to this issue. Thanks.

Comment: If you want a specific answer you will need to explain your specific environment.  Unfortunately, your question sounds as if you're talking about code files AND media type files (images, uploaded files, etc.).  They are 2 different things and will be handled differently.

Answer (score 2):

Kentico web farm by default synchronizes physical files automatically if the web farm is working properly. As each request can be served by different server Kentico serializes file binary into Database which is shared by all servers and then re-creates file on the server where it is missing.

I'm not aware of any situation where web farms are supported, but file synchronization isn't. It's either all or nothing, there is no middle solution.

Can you be more specific of why the synchronization of physical files is not working on your end? As long as all servers see the database (which they should otherwise the WF is not working at all) the file synchronization will work.

PS: If your files are not synchronized, go to **Web farm -> Tasks** application and check how many tasks are there. If there are no tasks (or very few which are being deleted constantly) then your web farms are working, if there are tasks older then few minutes then your web farms are not working at all.

Comment: Hi. It's not a case of web farms not working. We have been advised by Kentico that in our setup we need to synchronize files manually. We have multiple sites on a single domain (https://docs.kentico.com/plugins/servlet/mobile#content/view/5215199) on a load balanced architecture. Kentico documentation isn't clear but it turns out the multi-site-single-domain approach doesn't support load balancing, hence their advise that we must handle the web farm sync mechanism manually.

Comment: If its really the case you really might need to use 3rd party software to sync to files. However, do you really (I mean really) need to have those sites on the same domain? Why not use sub domains or different domains all together? It will be much easier to maintain and you will not encounter issues such as these.

Comment: Haha, believe me I do. This is for a giant global business and this is their requirement. We tried to talk them out of it! So my question remains, what is the best solution to this? Custom sync code, best 3rd party app etc?

Comment: Okay, so since it seems that your sites are using the same kentico instance (therefore they actually share resources) why do you need to have those sites separed? It all comes down to how you structure your content in the Pages application, right? You van have subfolders for different 'parts' of your site so you can still keep the content nicely organized. I would seriously consider this approach. Otherwise you might need to some tool for sync, but unfortunaly Im not that experienced with them. I had a client who had a simple batch script do sync the files, but there are better tools:)

Comment: Seriously, there's no alternative to this structure. This is a *.com/country structure where each country has its own culture set and nav structure.

Answer (score -1):

I read the thread above and would recommend you take a look at this tool from BizStream: https://devnet.kentico.com/marketplace/modules/compare-for-kentico

I haven't gotten to play with it myself, but they are a top notch shop so I can bet its a top notch product.

Otherwise you are going to have to go the custom sync code.

We've tried to do moves via the SQL Tables and it is 'possible', but the amount of interconnected relationships just make it quite unrealistic to build or support.

Comment: Hi Virgil. Thanks for the comment. I've seen that Bitstream tool before but that is for comparing Kentico objects between different instances. My challenge is syncing physical files between servers load balanced for the same Kentico instance. So not sure if your advice is relevant. But thanks anyway.

Comment: Sorry about that, early morning misread...should wait until I've had coffee.

Comment: We've used http://www.goodsync.com/ a couple of times and been very happy with it.